# Row Operations in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, row

I have a Spark DataFrame, like the one shown below.

I need an algorithm that whenever I find 'M' in the row, I need to select the next two columns after 'M' and create a new row. If there are two 'M' in a single row, then I need to create two rows 1 with the two columns from first 'M' and 2nd row with two columns from second 'M'.

Input Dataframe:

```
+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+-----------+----+                            
|rownum|_c0|                 _c1|_c2|     _c3|     _c4|  _c5| _c6| _c7| _c8|  _c9|_c10|_c11|  
+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+-----------+---

|     1|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45796416|50021|M|Drinks|30|M|Food|20| 

|     2|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45794779|50022|M|Food|40| M|Bar |50|M|Drinks|100

+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+-----------+----+-----+
```

New Output Dataframe:

```
+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+-------                             
|rownum|_c0| _c1|_c2|     _c3|     _c4|  _c5| _c6|        _c7| _c8|  _c9|   
+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+-------

|     1|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45796416|50021|M|Drinks|30|

|     1|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45796416|50021|M|Food|20|

|     2|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45794779|50022|M|Food|40|

|     2|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45794779|50022|M|Bar |50|

|     2|CS1|Jack Binions | 19|20191122|45794779|50022|M|Drinks |100|

+------+---+--------------------+---+--------+--------+-----+----+--+
```

Comment: `split` and then `explode`

Comment: How did you get this data? It seems the last columns should be in an array format, as the length is variable.